# Cant run GLSL code in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, opengl

Im trying to learn openGL and GLSL, And I rather be in Ubuntu. The problem is that I cant run my GLSL code. When I use

```
const GLubyte *shaderVersion = glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION);
std::cout<<shaderVersion<<std::endl;
```

The output is this: 1.30
and when I run `glxinfo | grep OpenG` in terminal, I get This lines:

```
    fingolfin@fingolfin:~$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.1.0-devel (git-2496cfd 2015-10-10 vivid-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.1.0-devel (git-2496cfd 2015-10-10 vivid-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 11.1.0-devel (git-2496cfd 2015-10-10 vivid-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

as you can see the `OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30` and I think this is my problem. I have my NVIDIA graphics updated, But I think the program runs on my Intel HD graphics so it wont work due to the low version of my GLSL. Is there any way to have a higher version of GLSL with my HD graphics? or is there any way for me to run my program using my other graphics card(NVIDIA)?

Im using QtCreator and QT to run my codes, It would be great if I could just tell QT to use my other graphics card.

**EDIT:** Based on the comment below I used nvidia-prime to switch to my nvidia graphics, Now `glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)` return 4.40. And everything looks fine

Comment: I think you can use nvidia-settings to change active graphics card. sudo apt-get nvidia-settings if you don't have it installed already.

Comment: @warsac Iv tryed but it did not work. I choose my nvidia as the default graphics card but again i faced that problem.

Comment: I am using nvidia-prime to force using the nvidia gpu. Use prime-select nvidia to switch to nvidia. I usually need to restart the machine for it to take effect.

Comment: @bofjas I tried nvidia-prime and it worked. now glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) returns 4.40. Thank you.